# send data through ussd code in android

Tags: java, android

I have an Activity where user can enter phone number and value . After the user inserts a details the info should be sent to the Service provider( telco)  and the Service will run in background.

how can i use ussd code to sent those information to service provider?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String encodedHash = Uri.encode("#");
String ussd = "*" + encodedHash + "12345" + encodedHash;
startActivityForResult(new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL", Uri.parse("tel:" + ussd)), 1);
```

Comment: hi @NIPHIN can i use emulator to test this code or i should go live

Comment: go live, it'll be better

Comment: Hi @NIPHIN thanks the code is working,
but if i use ussd code its not secure 
so plan to use webservice i have insert the ussd code in webservice
and i want call the webservice and its sent the ussd code+mobileno+value to telco, could you please advise on this. Thankss!